# Elsarticle class title note problem

Tags: elsarticle

I am trying to compile a latex file using the elsarticle class. I am going through the elsevier article template:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Elsevier \LaTeX\ template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}
\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}

\author{Elsevier\fnref{myfootnote}}
\address{Radarweg 29, Amsterdam}
\fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}

\author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{Elsevier Inc}
\ead[url]{www.elsevier.com}

\author[mysecondaryaddress]{Global Customer Service\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{support@elsevier.com}

\address[mymainaddress]{1600 John F Kennedy Boulevard, Philadelphia}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{360 Park Avenue South, New York}

\begin{abstract}
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

\section{The Elsevier article class}

\paragraph{Installation} If the document class \emph{elsarticle} is not available on your computer, you can download and install the system package \emph{texlive-publishers} (Linux) or install the \LaTeX\ package \emph{elsarticle} using the package manager of your \TeX\ installation, which is typically \TeX\ Live or Mik\TeX.

\paragraph{Usage} Once the package is properly installed, you can use the document class \emph{elsarticle} to create a manuscript. Please make sure that your manuscript follows the guidelines in the Guide for Authors of the relevant journal. It is not necessary to typeset your manuscript in exactly the same way as an article, unless you are submitting to a camera-ready copy (CRC) journal.

\paragraph{Functionality} The Elsevier article class is based on the standard article class and supports almost all of the functionality of that class. In addition, it features commands and options to format the
\begin{itemize}
\item document style
\item baselineskip
\item front matter
\item keywords and MSC codes
\item theorems, definitions and proofs
\item lables of enumerations
\item citation style and labeling.
\end{itemize}

\section{Front matter}

The author names and affiliations could be formatted in two ways:
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item Group the authors per affiliation.
\item Use footnotes to indicate the affiliations.
\end{enumerate}
See the front matter of this document for examples. You are recommended to conform your choice to the journal you are submitting to.

\section{Bibliography styles}

There are various bibliography styles available. You can select the style of your choice in the preamble of this document. These styles are Elsevier styles based on standard styles like Harvard and Vancouver. Please use Bib\TeX\ to generate your bibliography and include DOIs whenever available.

Here are two sample references: \cite{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.

\section*{References}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

I got the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \X@mytitlenote 
l.40 \end{frontmatter}
```

It clearly refers to the title note. In fact, if I remove from the title the following lines everything works.

```
\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}
\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.
```

Any suggestion about how I can solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's because the labels are not yet updated in the `.aux` file. Running again worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why, it's my first time using this, but after these step, it works, all I can do is put ??? under my head
step1:

```
\title{Elsevier \LaTeX template\tnoteref{}}
```

compile, and step2:

```
\title{Elsevier \LaTeX template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}
```

compile, step3:

```
\title{Elsevier \LaTeX\ template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}
```

Done! It works, so I think the problem maybe comes from compiler, not from code or software configuration, I use Tex live 2018 by the way.